# Push checkbox values into session storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, session-storage

am trying to push the same array values of setRooms React hook to sessionStorage but I only get TypeError: prev is not iterable for the sessionStorage

```
  {bedRooms.map((a, i) => (
    <FormControlLabel
      key={i}
      control={
        <Checkbox
          onChange={(event) => {
            const checkedValues = (prev) =>
              event.target.checked ? [...prev, a.roomsLabel] : [];

            sessionStorage.setItem("rooms", checkedValues());

            setRooms(checkedValues);
          }}
        />
      }
      label={a.roomsLabel}
      value={a.roomsLabel}
      checked={
        sessionStorage.getItem("rooms") &&
        sessionStorage.getItem("rooms") === a.roomsLabel &&
        true
      }
    />
  ))}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pushing objects or arrays in session/local storage is not possible

Try this :

When saving to the session storage :

```
sessionStorage.setItem("rooms", JSON.stringify(checkedValues()));
```

When retrieving data from session storage :

```
JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("rooms"))
```

Comment: I still have "TypeError: prev is not iterable" but I will explore more with this info. Thank you!